# Authenticating firebase user before a test suite

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, redux, jestjs

I'm trying to run some tests on a react-native component, but the component won't show data because it's trying to get data form firebase.

The approach I'm going for now is to authenticate as a test user I've setup in firebase, then render the component. Expected result should be a list populated with users. But that's not what I'm getting.

I'm not quite sure which piece of code would be most relevant so please request which bits you'd like to see.

Comment: You could consider mocking such requests, so that your test suite doesn't actually rely on an external 3rd party service.

Comment: @b2m9 That's an approach I've thought about too, not quire sure how I should go about it though, a lot of people saying not to mock redux because using your actual code base's store is better for test confidence, on the other hand mocking external APIs seem like a bad idea.